# DevExpress Gridview selection count is 1 but the row is not selected

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I'm trying to select gridview row in code source, ı'm using that code block: grdList.Selection.SelectRowByKey("value");

this code is selecting row in the gridview but i can't see the selection on the view , i can get count of selected row 1 but i can't see that on the page,

what is wrong?

grdList.Selection.SelectRowByKey("value");

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your scenario is similar to the one described in the [How to select Grid View rows on the sever](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T687393/how-to-select-grid-view-rows-on-the-sever) ticket and the SelectRowByKey method is called during a callback to the server. In this case, call the grid's client-side [PerformCallback](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/js-ASPxClientGridView.PerformCallback(args)) method and handle the server-side [CustomCallback](https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.CustomCallback) event to select grid rows.

Comment: i'm using an linkbutton for select gridview's rows.
i am using 4 gridview and 4 link button in the same page every button is working just for 1 gridview 3 button is working with selectall-unselectall methods and 4. button have " grdList.Selection.SelectRowByKey("value"); " command , if the problem is callback  other gridviews must not work. Am i wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in a newly created app (see my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/AleksandrKostik/SelectRowDemo)). Please check if you can modify the source code to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I fixed problem, i deleted devexpress and reinstal my problem is fixed.
Thnx for your help  Alex